# Bash: Looping through a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a variable `Vmac` that stores values of multiple MAC addresses, collected from `wmic` call as follows:

```
Vmac=`wmic --delimiter="," --authentication-file=/path/to/file //IP-ADDR "Select AdapterType,MACAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapter" | grep "Ethernet" | awk -F, '{print $3}'| sort | uniq | tr '\n' ' '`
```

It has been observed that, the number of values contained in the `Vmac` variable varies in the range from 1 to 5, for different hosts. I have to separate each of them and store them into a variable `VmacN`, where N can take values from 1 to 5.

For some hosts, there can be only one MAC Address, so it would have only `Vmac1` available. Whereas, host  with 4 NICs (and hence MAC Addresses) would have `Vmac1`, `Vmac2`, `Vmac3` and `Vmac4`.

In order to tabularize this information efficiently, I also need to store the value `NA` in the `VmacN` variables, where less MAC addresses are available (e.g. for machine with 1 NIC, `Vmac1` will be `AA:BB:CC:DD`, while `Vmac2` through `Vmac5` will be `NA`. While for machine with 4 NICs, only `Vmac5` will be `NA`).

For this purpose, I created and tested a piece of code, which is as follows:

```
if [ ! -z "$Vmac" ]
then
        i=1
       for mac in $Vmac
        do
             declare "Vmac${i}"="$mac"
                ((i++))
        done
fi
printf "${Vmac1:-NA}"",""${Vmac2:-NA}"",""${Vmac3:-NA}"
```

Output:

```
3C:40:20:52:41:53 88:51:FB:3F:0D:81 C8:CB:B8:CC:5F:D2,NA,NA
```

When printed only `Vmac1`, it would print entire MAC addresses (i.e. value of `Vmac`).

I suppose, I am going wrong in iterating through `Vmac`.

How to iterate through a variable which holds a string value?

Comment: It is not a good idea to declare variable(s) in such way:`declare "Vmac${i}"="$mac"`. Much better use array `Vmac[i]=$mac`. But if you want you can use `eval Vmac$i=\$mac`

Comment: Nit picks: (1) Rather than `sort | uniq`, can you use `sort -u`? (2) Inside `\`...\`` or `$(...)`, you don't need `| tr '\n' ' '` -- the shell will do that for you, automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an array. For example:

```
## read the MACs into an array
declare -a Vmac=( $(wmic --delimiter="," --authentication-file=/path/to/file \
            //IP-ADDR "Select AdapterType,MACAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapter" | 
             grep "Ethernet" | awk -F, '{print $3}'| sort | uniq | tr '\n' ' ' )

## Add NAs as appropriate
for((i=0;i<6;i++)); do 
    [ -z "${Vmac[i]}" ] && Vmac[i]="NA" 
done
```

To illustrate:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a vmac=( $(echo 3C:40:20:52:41:53 88:51:FB:3F:0D:81 C8:CB:B8:CC:5F:D2))
for((i=0;i<6;i++)); do 
    [ -z "${vmac[i]}" ] && vmac[i]="NA" 
done
echo "${vmac[@]}"
```

Output:

```
3C:40:20:52:41:53 88:51:FB:3F:0D:81 C8:CB:B8:CC:5F:D2 NA NA NA
```

Comment: This won't create `Vmac1` through `Vmac5`, but will create `Vmac[0]` through `Vmac[4]`, if I am not wrong. But, I hope, it will surely fulfill my purpose. I will check and update you.

Comment: @MandarShinde yes, it won't create variables called `Vmac1` through `5`. That is on purpose. Using such variable names is needlessly complex and, while possible with `eval` as [Costas suggested](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189945/bash-looping-through-a-string#comment317236_189945) it will just make your code that much harder to read and that much harder to write. This is precisely what arrays are for.

Comment: If you could tell me where I went wrong with my code, that would be a great help too.

Comment: @MandarShinde you were trying to iterate over a string. That won't work. `for mac in $Vmac` runs once for the entire string, all the MACs saved: `f="a b c"; for i in "$f"; do echo $i; done`. The spaces are part of the string so you can't iterate over it, it has only a single element, the string itself.

Comment: Could you please tell why should we use `declare -a var=( $(..) )` while we can do `var=( $(..) )` i mean any added advantage/caveat?

Comment: @heemayl none as far as I know. I just added it here to clarify that this is an array.